# React: get compile warnings without actually compiling

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app created using `create-react-app`.

The git repository has a CI with to stages:

- test: on all branches, just executes `yarn test`
- build: on master only, builds the frontend (`yarn build`) and the docker image

I see that, if I have some warnings when compiling (like unused imports, or missing useEffect dependencies, just as examples), `yarn build` returns warnings that (rightly) make the CI fail at build stage. Those warnings are the same I get when using `yarn start` while developing.

However, I'd like to catch this at test stage, not at build stage, so that I can avoid to merge in master before noticing there's something wrong.

I see there are some solutions like `unused-webpack-plugin`, but I'd rather not add anything more to the dependencies just for this: I'm wondering if there's a method using the tools React already provide, given the fact that it's already doing this check when building or debugging.

Thanks